# Change background image on hover with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a scope of 's with their background images, but I can't figure out how to make them change. I tried several variants, but none of them has passed. Here's the code:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController" class="main">
    <div ng-repeat="land in lands" class="col-md-9" ng-style="{ 'background-image': 'url({{ land.cover }})'}">
        <p>{{ land.name }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.lands = [
        {
            cover: 'img/norway.jpg',
            cover1: 'img/norway1.jpg',
            name: 'Norway'
        },
        {
            cover: 'img/sweden.jpg',
            cover1: 'img/sweden1.jpg',
            name: 'Sweden'
        },
        {
            cover: 'img/denmark.jpg',
            name: 'Danmark'
        },
        {
            cover: 'img/iceland.jpg',
            name: 'Iceland',
        },
        {
            cover: 'img/finland.jpg',
            name: 'Finland'
        },
        {
            cover: 'img/estonia.jpg',
            name: 'Estonia'
        }
    ];
}]);
```

Comment: literally I want  {{ land.cover }} change on hover to {{ land.cover1 }}

Comment: is it not working for you? maybe add a plnkr to your question

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/KwcvgrzfHhkrWn17e4b2?p=preview here is it

Comment: where u have written any code to change ur image from cover to cover1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use interpolation tags in the expression context. Should be:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController" class="main">
    <div ng-repeat="land in lands" class="col-md-9" 
         ng-init="coverImage = land.cover" 
         ng-mouseover="coverImage = land.cover"
         ng-mouseout="coverImage = land.cover1"
         ng-style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + coverImage + ')' }">
        <p>{{ land.name }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've fixed tags but still don't know how to make background image change. I suppose I should use ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave, but have no idea how to use them properly in this situation :(

Comment: Check my answer, it has all the answers to your situation, ngMouseover and ngMouseout.

Comment: upvoted for simplicity - the ng-init approach never occurred to me :)

Comment: @dfsq thanks a lot! that really simplified everything!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to respond to the DOM, the angular way of doing this would be to create a directive.

Working code is available [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/nFMwA2lko8ryHDAihLDz). The summary of the solution is this:

Your DOM will change to this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="land in ctrl.lands" hover-bg-change default-bg="land.cover" hover-bg="land.cover1" class='tile'>
        <p>{{ land.name }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive will look like this:

```
app.directive('hoverBgChange', ['$parse', function ($parse)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, $el, attrs)
        {
            var defaultBg = $parse(attrs.defaultBg)(scope);
            var hoverBg = $parse(attrs.hoverBg)(scope);

            $el.css('background-image', 'url('+defaultBg+')');

            $el.on('mouseover', function ()
            {
                $el.css('background-image', 'url('+hoverBg+')');
            })
            .on('mouseout', function ()
            {
                $el.css('background-image', 'url('+defaultBg+')');
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: @dfsq's solution is a much simpler solution. If changing bg image is all you need, you'd be better off with that solution :)

Comment: yes, but I tried his variant and it didn't work :( but your variant does exactly what I need

Comment: I tried that approach, and it works as well. Updated the plunker to show that approach. I recommend you go with that approach - less code is more maintainable code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it work in one go.
My solution would be 
define css as

```
.hover-out{
background-image: url('img/norway.jpg');
}

.hover-in{
background-image: url('img/norway1.jpg');
}
```

In markup

```
<div ng-controller="mainController" class="main">
    <div ng-repeat="land in lands" class="col-md-9" ng-class="{'hover-out':hoverOut[$index], 'hover-in':!hoverOut[$index]}" ng-mouseover="hoverOut[$index] = false" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut[$index] = true">
        <p>{{ land.name }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: urpalreloaded unfortunately it doesn't work :( i made it as you've shown, but now the <div>'s have totally dissapeared